# How to avoid "redefinition; different basic types" when trying to implement PIMPL idom

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I am trying to use the PIMPL idiom -- hiding the implementation details of a class from the user. I also want to go one step further, by hiding the actual name of the implementation class. This should also allow me to quickly swap the implementation class by changing a single line of code.

My approach is as follows:

In the header file I define a `Public` class and declare a proxy name `Implementation` of what would be the implementation class.

**X.h:**

```
#pragma once

namespace detail {
class Implementation;
}

class Public {
public:
  Public();
  void foo();
private:
  detail::Implementation* data;
};
```

Within the implementation I define the actual implementation class (under a different name) and then use a typedef to set `Implementation` to be that class of my choosing.

**X.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "X.h"

namespace {
class Private { //the actual implementation class. Everything about it, including its name, should be hidden
public:
  void foo() { std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl; }
};
}

namespace detail {
typedef Private Implementation; //set Private as the actual Implementation
}

Public::Public() : data(new detail::Implementation()) {}

void Public::foo() {
  data->foo();
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

```
error C2371: 'detail::Implementation': redefinition; different basic types
```

in the `typedef` line. But in both locations (cpp and h files) I declare a class; one with a definition provided, the other without. So what am I missing?

If `typedef` (or C++11 `using`) cannot be used because of reasons, how else can I achieve my goal?

---

I have seen similar questions about the same error, but all I found were some trivial errors, such as:

- [Error C2371: redefinition; different basic types - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424239/error-c2371-redefinition-different-basic-types-why) : uses a name before its definition
- [Redefinition; different basic types (typedef struct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670596/redefinition-different-basic-types-typedef-struct), or [Redefinition different basic types => typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100179/redefinition-different-basic-types-typedef) : an include guard is forgotten

Answer (score 1):

Put your typedef in your header file and remove the declaration of `Implementation`.

You are declaring `Implementation` twice. Once at `class Implementation;` and again at `typedef Private Implementation;`

If you want to hide the `Private` type make `Public` templated:

```
template<typename Implementation>
class Public
{
     ......
     Implementation * data;
     ......
};
```

Then in your cpp you can declare it with your private implementation as :

```
Public<Private> my_thing;
```

Even better you can hide the template using typedef as you originally planned:

```
typedef Public<Private> ExposedClass
```

Comment: If I put typedef in the header, I expose `Private` name - that's something I want to avoid. Yes, I declare `Implementation` twice, but it is twice the same thing: a class.

Comment: @CygnusX1 it is not *the same thing*. One is a typedef, the other is a (forward declaration of a) class. Note the error clang produces is a little more verbose: `typedef redefinition with different types ('(anonymous namespace)::Private' vs 'detail::Implementation')`

Comment: If you truly want to hide the ````Private```` name, make ````Public```` a templated class which takes the implementation type as its template parameter.

Comment: Making `Public` templated hides nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

> define the actual implementation class (under a different name) and then use a typedef to set Implementation to be that class of my choosing.

That's the problem. You can't. A typedef name is not a class. By saying `class Implementation`, you promise `Implementation` will be defined as an actual class, not a typedef name.

Get rid of the `typedef` and rename `Private` to `Implementation`.